# UI Picker View Personalization

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios5, customization, uipickerview

I am trying to find a way for a UIPicker to have the options of 3, 6, 12, 24, 36, 46, 72. Such that the user would be able to select the options from that set. But the UIPicker must come with a spinning wheel default starting from 1 and progressing through the above set.

So selecting this option should eventually put the selected Quantity In the Shopping cart.

Comment: Have you looked at the UIPickerViewDelegate documentation? http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate.html

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need to do. In the .h of the file that has the picker you need to implement `UIPickerViewDataSource` and `UIPickerViewDelegate`:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate>
```

You will then need to connect the UIPicker's DataSource and Delegate to the file's owner. Then you will need to implement these methods, I got you started on them.

```
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
     return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
     return self.myArray.count;
}

// getting the selected row and therefore the selected value
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
     self.selectedValue = [self.myArray objectAtIndex:row];
}

// The text displayed in each picker view
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
     return [self.myArray objectAtIndex:row];
}

// Properties used in the above code.

// myArray is the array with the values you want in it, so you could make it a property do lazy loading
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *myArray;

- (NSArray *)myArray {
     if (!_myArray) _myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"3", @"6", ..., nil];
     return myArray;
}

// selectedValue is an NSString of the current number selected
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *selectedValue;
```

I just coded this up in StackOverflow so I apologize if there are any syntax errors.